# Bootstrap 5 Components Page Layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How can I replicate the layout used by Bootstrap on their components page ?
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/

I am referring to the 2 column layout with dual scroll. Left column appears to be sticky bottom somehow.

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column flex-sm-row">
<div>SideBar</div>
<div>Page Content</div>
```

Comment: The documentation has many examples of how to put together the components into many different layouts. I think you should be able to find several of the items you're looking for right there. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/

Comment: The sidebar examples on that page give an indication of what would go into my first div. I am more interested in the utilities for the overall layout.